# Replacing GET with POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here I am trying to redirect new page and I want to send a variable. It uses GET.

How can I do it with POST?

```
window.location.href = 'start.php?userid='+userid;
```

start.php

```
<?php
    $user_id=$_GET['userid']; //should be post
?>
```

Comment: Why would you need to use a `POST`?

Comment: Also note that you need to use `encodeURIComponent` when passing variable names and values manually.

Comment: @moonwave99: it's prone to be hacked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to submit the data to the server, not just redirect the browser.

In your case, as it looks like you want full page refresh anyway just create a form on the fly:

```
var oForm = document.createElement("form");
oForm.method = "POST";
oForm.action = "start.php";
var oInput = document.createElement("input");
oInput.name = "userid";
oInput.value = userid;
oForm.appendChild(oInput);
document.body.appendChild(oForm);
oForm.submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a fake form in HTML and a link that will trigger javascript to submit the form, like below

```
<form action="start.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="[userid]">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitlink() 
{
document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
<a class="buttondown" onclick="submitlink()">Submit Link</a>
```

Comment: How can I get which var I have posted and how to receive it at another end/?

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer may help you:
[How do you force a web browser to use POST when getting a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651197/how-do-you-force-a-web-browser-to-use-post-when-getting-a-url/1651206#1651206)

You just need to create a form on demand using javascript to send data with POST method when clicking a link.
So basically it's just this part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitAsPost(url) {
    var postForm = document.createElement('form');
    postForm.action = url;
    postForm.method = 'post';
    var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    bodyTag.appendChild(postForm);
    postForm.submit();
}
</script>
<a href="/my/url" onclick="submitAsPost(this.href); return false;">this is my post link</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same problem you had. If you are using jquery.redirect.min.js as your jquery plugin, You can use as below. It gives you **POST** method.

```
   $().redirect("myPhp.php", { name: "John" });
```

All you need is to ***download jquery.redirect.min.js file*** from [here](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=Hxwu9nIdbtARYD0W7vDIsVEhkRs&cid=mXRq0hPeXzU&s=&browser=Default&fp=305970&mp&projSelected=true#L0) and ***link it with your php file***, and use as above. That's it. Hope I helped.

Works fine for me.

Comment: Does it use 'POST' method by default for the redirection?

Comment: Yes it does. Default method is 'POST' for this one.

Comment: Aha. Generally, the pluging just does the same what another answers suggested but in easy way. So, +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can post form by html tag  and . Otherwise, see ["jQuery.post"](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for async post.
For the 1st case you create FORM tag, put INPUT type="hidden" inside and set its value that will be posted.

Comment: please only ajax call. I could not use jquery

Comment: @Karimkhan http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp see "Post requests" section

Comment: Don't recommend w3schools.com as a reference. It's full of errors, see http://w3fools.com.

Comment: Unless a jQuery answer is asked for, or it's in the tags please don't answer a question using jQuery. It is not a standard.