# WaitForInputIdle not waiting for website to fully display

Tags: delphi, wait, createprocess

I looked high and low and could not find a satisfactory answer to my problem, which is:
I want to open a website and send it my user id and my password to enter it.  I am using a procedure found on StackOverflow that uses  CreateProcess and WaitForInputIdle.  The problem is that the procedure returns without waiting for the website to fully display, therefore my Id and password end up in the wrong place.  Inserting a Sleep(5000) will most of the time work but is not reliable.  Can anybody point me in the right direction.

Comment: This doesn't work for the obvious reason. When you open a new web page you can interact with the browser before the page has finished loading. You need to wait for it to finish loading. Perhaps easier would be to host the browser in your process which would give you better control.

Comment: See [WaitForInputIdle should really be called WaitForProcessStartupComplete](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100325-00/?p=14493) and [WaitForInputIdle waits for any thread, which might not be the thread you care about](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100326-00/?p=14483) for why `WaitForInputIdle()` behaves the way it does.

Comment: It surely shouldn't wait. Have you found the documentation for `WaitForInputIdle` on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1):

That will never work because `WaitForInputIdle` returns as soon as the application is waiting for input, but the web browser will not load the web site before that.

You'd have to find another way to do what you want. For example you could create a html form that will post your user id and password to the desired website as soon as it is opened:
[How do you force a web browser to use POST when getting a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651197/how-do-you-force-a-web-browser-to-use-post-when-getting-a-url)

Or host the webbrowser in your application. Then it's in your control and you can send the post by code or be notified when the website has finished loading.